# Cleaning up data in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

is there a way to 'clean up ' data in TensorFlow, similarly to what you can do with pandas?
If not , is there a way to use pandas as input of a Tensorflow computation?
Right now the only way i can do that is to 
- read file in pandas
- clean up data (via panda)
- store csv file
- read the csv file using tensorfow api

thanks in advance and regards
 Marco